# Can I create a index for array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This is a record in mongodb.

```
{
  numbers: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

As title, If I create an indexing in mongo like

```
{
  numbers: 1
}
```

It will works? Or index works only on single value like number or string type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can and it works:

> To index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB creates an index
> key for each element in the array. These multikey indexes support
> efficient queries against array fields. Multikey indexes can be
> constructed over arrays that hold both scalar values [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) (e.g.
> strings, numbers) and nested documents.

please visit the doc: [Mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)

Comment: Thank you. The example is nested array so I miss it